# How can I make a SAX DefaultHandler ignore implicit newlines?

Tags: java, xml

I created a class that extends SAX DefaultHandler.  To get a value in between tags, I do:

```
private static class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private String str;
    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws   
    SAXException {
            String current = new String(ch, start, length);
            str+=current;
        }
    }
```

This works if the closing tag is on the same line, but if the xml looks like this:

```
<string name="sentence">The fox runs\nover the hill into the pasture
    </string>
```

It renders as:

```
"The fox runs\nover the hill into the pasture
    "
```

Instead of

```
"the fox runs
over the hill into the pasture"
```

I can't use trim() because the string can look like "The fox runs\nover the hill into the pasture\n"

Answer (score 1):

The key thing here is whether the white space inside the tag is significant or not. If it's not significant you can strip out extra whitespace. And that can be done with a simple regex.

```
 str += current.replaceAll("\\s{2,}$", "")
```

This regex will trim the line if it contains at least two white spaces (be it space + new line or any other combination) at the end of the line. If the line is all whitespace it will be removed completely.

However it will leave unchanged

> The fox runs\nover the hill into the pasture\n

If you want to handle the situation where the user accidently type `\n\n` instead of just `\n` you could make a slight change

```
str += current.replaceAll("\\s{2,}$", "\n")
```

Comment: whitespace should, including an explicit "\n".  If it's just a linebreak due to a user entered carriage return, no.  Is it possible to differentiate between an explicit newline aka "\n" and one that just starts a new line, in this case to close the tag?

Comment: going through some old answer I notice that I have missed replying to a comment from you. Did you manage to sort it out?